# Pit in LSTM programming by python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

As we all Know, if we want to train a LSTM network, we must reshape the train dataset by the function `numpy.reshape()`, and reshaping result is like `[samples,time_steps,features]`. However, the new shape is influenced by the original one. I have seen some blogs teaching LSTM programming taking 1 as time_steps, and if time_steps is another number, samples will change relevently. My question is that *does the `samples`equal to `batch_size`?*

`X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, samples is different from batch_size. samples is the total number of samples you would have. batch_size would be the size of each batch or the number of samples per each batch used in training, like by .fit.

For example, if samples=128 and batch_size=16, then your data would be divided into 8 batches with each having 16 samples inside during .fit call.

As another note, time_steps is the total time steps or observations within each sample. It does not make much sense to have it as 1 with LSTM as the main advantage of RNN's in general is to learn the temporal patterns. With time_step=1, there won't be any history to leverage. Here as an example that might help:

Assume that your job is to determine if someone is active or not every hour by looking at they breathing rate and heart rate provided every minute, i.e. 2 features measured at 60 samples per hour. (This is just an example, use accelerometers if you really wanted to do this :)) Let's say you have 128 hours of labeled data. Then your input data would be of shape (128, 60, 2) and your output would be of shape (128, 1).

Here, you have 128 samples, 60 time steps or observations per sample, and two features.

Next you split the data into train, validation, and testing according to the samples. For example, your train, validation, and test data would be of shapes (96, 60, 2), (16, 60, 2), and (16, 60, 2), respectively.

If you use batch_size=16, your training, validation, and test data would have 6, 1, and 1 batches, respectively.

Comment: I am little confused about `time_steps` from your answer, can you take an example to make it clear? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It really makes the problem clear, thanks for your help.

Comment: **With time_step=1, there won't be any history to leverage.**      

However, there exists some examples written in blogs taking 1 as time_steps   and it does make good predictions, how can I explain this? Besides, Is there superior method to choose a better time_steps?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share the link where step_size of 1 is being used? Are you share they have input data with step_size of 1? Also, there is a "state_full" option that might be leveraged with LSTM's which you can read about. Then step_size of size 1 may give some history advantage as the states do not reset, but even with that, step_size=1 won't be my choice.

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/    

the author of the  blog answered that **The LSTMs have memory that is reset between batches, or manually if you choose. Conceptually, this memory is separate from the number of time steps in one sample.**  So, which one determines the memory of LSTM? How can I confirm the length of memory of LSTM?

Comment: I see where the confusion comes from now. The author wants to make a prediction at a given time based on look_back observations. First, the author stacks all the the data points and puts them at one time step. Thus the input shape becomes (1, look_back). This is poor choice as it does not take advantage of the fact the data points have time-dependency. This is also mentioned in the post, I think. In a second approach, he uses the actual window, thus the input shape becomes (look_back, 1). Finally, the author talks about state_full options which we discussed.

Answer (score 0):

No. Samples are not equal to batch size. Samples means the number of rows in your data-set. Your training data-set is divided into number of batches and pass it to the network to train.

In simple words,

Imagine your data-set has 30 samples, and you define your batch_size as 3. 
That means the 30 samples divided into 10 batches(30 divided by you defined batch_size = 10). When you train you model, at a time only 3 rows of data will be be pushed to the neural network and then next 3 rows will be push to the neural network. Like wise whole data-set will push to the neural network.

*Samples/Batch_size = Number of batches*

Remember that batch_size and number of batches are two different things.

Comment: However, training dataset has to be reshaped like the form of `[samples, time_steps, features]` , when I want to reshape the my training dataset to the specified shape with time_steps not being 1 and features always being the number of columns of training dataset, I have to change the value of samples, how does this happen? How to understand `time_steps ` practically?